# Appending to a file in a zip archive

Tags: c++, zip, miniz

I have written a zip class that uses functions and code from miniz to: Open an archive, Close an archive, Open a file in the archive, Close a file in the archive, and write to the currently open file in the archive.

Currently opening a file in an archive overwrites it if it already exists. I would like to know if it is possible to APPEND to a file within a zip archive that has already been closed?

I want to say that it is possible but I would have to edit all offsets in each of the other file's internal states and within the central directory. If it is possible - is this the right path to look in to?

Note: 
 I deal with large files so decompressing and compressing again is not ideal and neither is doing any copying of files. I would just like to "open" a file in the zip archive to continue writing compressed data to it.

Comment: Since in a zip file appending something to the data and then zipping doesn't result in appending something to the file, but rather in changing it in multiple plaes, I figure that's impossible. Zipping is possible due to correlations between different data elements, so is non-local with respect to a certain data element.

Answer (score 1):

> I would just like to "open" a file in the zip archive to continue writing compressed data to it.

Compressed files aren't working like a file system or folder, where you could change individual files. They keep e.g. check sums, that need to apply for the whole archive.

So no, you can't do such *inplace*, but have to unpack the compressed file, apply your changes and compress everything again.

Comment: If I could get the file stats from the archive such as its local directory header, offset into the archive, etc... couldn't I just edit that information and write compressed data as if I were writing a new file into the archive?

Comment: @WillM Well, if your compression library API provides such featur, go forward with it.